# Adding more information on a simple SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I've been running some examples with SPARQL, and it looks pretty cool.

I'm using for the moment http://dbpedia.org/snorql

I'm trying to query Salty Desserts over there.

I can list Desserts using

```
     SELECT ?food 
     WHERE {   
       ?food rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Desserts>
     }
     ORDER BY ?name
```

How do I actually put on the query that the food has to be salty? Sorry if this seems to be a dumb question.

Comment: Did you actually see anything qualified as "salty" in DBPedia? Didn't find much so far: SELECT DISTINCT ?prop ?hasValue ?isValueOf
WHERE {
  { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Salty> ?prop ?hasValue }
  UNION
  { ?isValueOf ?prop <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Salty> }
  UNION
  { <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Salty> ?prop ?hasValue }
  UNION
  { ?isValueOf ?prop <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Salty> }
  UNION
  { <http://jv.dbpedia.org/resource/Asin> ?prop ?hasValue }
  UNION
  { ?isValueOf ?prop <http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource/Q1040909> }
} ORDER BY ?prop ?hasValue ?isValueOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were sufficient for it to have salt on the list of ingredients:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?food
 WHERE { 
   ?food rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Desserts> .
   ?food <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ingredient> :Salt .
 } ORDER BY ?food
```

Taste seemed a good lead, but:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf
WHERE {
  { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/taste> ?property ?hasValue }
  UNION
  { ?isValueOf ?property <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/taste> }
} ORDER BY ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf
```

All of this tested on [DBPedia snorql](http://dbpedia.org/snorql)